# First item of listview showing popup menu when it shouldn't

Tags: java, android, listview

So, I found this weird behavior listview that applying popup menu when a certain condition is met (on this case, if approval is "Unchecked" )

All item on the listview behave the way I expect, except the first item when value of approval is "Accept" or "Denied".

So, here is my code.
**Order.java**

```
package com.example.listview;

public class Order {
    String name;
    String approval;

    public Order(String name, String approval) {
        this.name = name;
        this.approval = approval;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getApproval() {
        return approval;
    }

    public void setApproval(String approval) {
        this.approval = approval;
    }
}
```

**OrderAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.listview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    List<Order> orders;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public OrderAdapter(Activity activity, List<Order> orders) {
        this.activity   = activity;
        this.orders      = orders;

        inflater        = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return orders.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (view == null){

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_order_item, viewGroup, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tvName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            holder.tvApproval = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_approval);
            holder.rlPopUpMenu = view.findViewById(R.id.rl_popUpMenu);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }else
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        final Order model = orders.get(i);

        holder.tvName.setText(model.getName());
        holder.tvApproval.setText(model.getApproval());
        holder.tvApproval.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D0CACA"));

        // Condition For PopUp Menu
        if(model.getApproval().equals("Unchecked")) {
            // Menu Popup
            holder.rlPopUpMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rlPopUpMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.order_item_popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                            if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_accept) {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, "You Click Accept", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                            if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_denied) {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, "You Click Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    popup.show();
                }
            });


        } else if(model.getApproval().equals("Accept")) {
            holder.tvApproval.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#32FF84"));
        } else if(model.getApproval().equals("Denied")) {
            holder.tvApproval.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1F9999"));
        }

        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvApproval;
        RelativeLayout rlPopUpMenu;
    }

}
```

**OrderActivity.java**

```
package com.example.listview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Order> orders;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("List View");

        final ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.order_scrollview);
        // To Scroll to the Top when Opening The Activity
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);

        final NonScrollListView non_scroll_list = (NonScrollListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_order);

        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(new Order("MikeA", "Accept"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeB", "Accept"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeC", "Unchecked"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeD", "Denied"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeE", "Unchecked"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeF", "Unchecked"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeG", "Unchecked"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeH", "Unchecked"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeI", "Accept"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeJ", "Unchecked"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeK", "Unchecked"));
        orders.add(new Order("MikeL", "Unchecked"));

        final OrderAdapter adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, orders);
        non_scroll_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**NonScrollListView.java**

```
package com.example.listview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {
    public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

Folder layout

**activity_order.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/order_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#F2F2F2"
    tools:context="com.example.listview.OrderActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="12dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F2F2F2">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#F2F2F2"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <com.example.listview.NonScrollListView
                    android:id="@+id/lv_order"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF">
                </com.example.listview.NonScrollListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**lv_order_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
    android:background="#991F1F">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_popUpMenu"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/three_dots_order"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_approval"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Folder menu
**order_item_popup_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_accept"
        android:title="Accept"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_denied"
        android:title="Denied"/>
</menu>
```

And here is the picture of the list
[image: ListView Image]

As you can see, MikeA's approval value is "Accept",
so the popup menu (the three dot) should not appear.
So, is there anything that I miss ?

Comment: try to put `holder.rlPopUpMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in the other `else if` statements in the `OrderAdapter`

Comment: Yeah, that works well @Yahya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this

```
 if(model.getApproval().equals("Unchecked")) {
        // Menu Popup
        holder.rlPopUpMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.rlPopUpMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.order_item_popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                        if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_accept) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "You Click Accept", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                        if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_denied) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "You Click Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();
            }
        });


    } else if(model.getApproval().equals("Accept")) {
        holder.rlPopUpMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvApproval.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#32FF84"));
    } else if(model.getApproval().equals("Denied")) {
        holder.rlPopUpMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvApproval.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1F9999"));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, It works. But that is weird, because in the xml file, I already set the visibility to gone , so that mean it should be gone by default, right?

Comment: The RecyclerView will recycle views, including their state, there's no guarantee that your re-used ViewHolder will still have Visibility Gone, you need to do it every time.

Comment: No, if you are using any condition for changing visibility than you have to set in every case

Comment: I need to wait 4 minutes, I will accept it. So, thank you Milan :)